# Can't get Rails 5.2 credentials to work while trying to hide AWS and JWT keys/secrets. Getting no method for Nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, token, credentials, rails-activestorage

I've been spending hours on this but cannot come up with any solutions. I've scoured the docs to see what I'm missing but can't find anything.

I'm using JWT and ActiveStorage with Amazon S3. I need to hide this keys before I can commit to Github. Following many examples, here's how my `credentials.yml.enc` file looks:

```
amazon:
key: <my access key for AWS S3>
secret: <my secret id for AWS S3>

jwt: <my jwt token encode/decode password>
```

I save this then in my `storage.yml` file I have:

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:amazon][:key] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:amazon][:secret] %>
  region: us-east-1
  bucket: your_own_bucket
```

I've also tried with

```
<%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:amazon][:key] %>
```

If I goto console and try `Rails.application.credentials[:amazon][:key]` or `Rails.application.credentials.amazon[:key]` or any other variants, it's always nil.

```
Rails.application.credentials
```

gives me:

```
 => #<ActiveSupport::EncryptedConfiguration:0x00007faf1284aa80 
@key_path=#<Pathname:/Users/demiansims/Development/Beastly/beastly- 
backend/config/master.key>, @content_path=# 
<Pathname:/Users/demiansims/Development/Beastly/beastly- 
backend/config/credentials.yml.enc>, @env_key="RAILS_MASTER_KEY", 
@raise_if_missing_key=false, @encryptor=# 
<ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor:0x00007faf1287bb80 
@secret=">^\x04\x9Bh\xFEb\x00\x8B\xB3O5\xDC\x8E\xA6b", 
@sign_secret=nil, @cipher="aes-128-gcm", @aead_mode=true, 
@verifier=ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::NullVerifier, 
@serializer=Marshal, @options={:cipher=>"aes-128-gcm"}, @rotations=[]>, 
@config={}
```

Comment: could you verify your `credentials.yml.enc` posted here, because it seems like it doesn't have spaces in the keys after `amazon`

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean by 'space'? I placed it just like the default. I also added a jwt: <my key here>

Comment: I couldn't paste the code here, so I added as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You credential file might not be saving your changes. I had this same problem. I was using sublime and `EDITOR="subl --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit` would bring up the editor but it would not recognize when I had saved the file. I never solved this, so I switched to vi. `EDITOR="vi" bin/rails credentials:edit` and problem solved. Now it all works as expected.  If you are not familiar with vi commands like me, these are helpful to know:

`i` -> "insert" will allow to move around with your arrow keys, delete, and add code
`esc` -> when you are finished editing hit escape
`:wq` -> this will save and exit the file. after you hit escape just type in :wq

hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem in the format of your `credentials.yml.enc` it should be like:

```
amazon:
  key: <my access key for AWS S3>
  secret: <my secret id for AWS S3>
  jwt: <my jwt token encode/decode password>
```

So you can access your key like `Rails.application.credentials.amazon[:key]`